# how to check JavaScript is enabled or not

Tags: javascript

```
    <html>
    <head></head
    <body>
    <noscript>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                display:none!important;
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>
    <header></header>
<div class="container">
    <p>actual body starts from here, if javascript enabled, it will display.</p>
</div>
<footer></footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I do not have any reputation in stackoverflow to answer this question. so, I created this question and answered. it will work in any apps java,dotnet, php etc., Thanks.

Comment: That's not how stack overflow works.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>
    <head></head
    <body>
    <noscript>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                display:none!important;
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>
    <header></header>
<div class="container">
    <p>actual body starts from here, if javascript enabled, it will display.</p>
</div>
<footer></footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. In your example, the `<p>` element will display all the time.

Comment: I think you meant to target `.container` in your CSS? Hiding the entire body will prevent showing an actual noscript message.

Comment: Answer needs explanation